# Appending EJS partial with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to use JQuery to append an EJS partial. What I want to do is to implement infinite scrolling in a table - I am using EJS to render the table's rows as partials and within each partial using more EJS to display the variables passed into the view from Express.

**table.html**

```
<tbody>
  <% include row.html %>
</tbody>
```

**row.html**

```
<% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
  ...and so on
<% }) %>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('tbody').append('<%- include row.html %>')
```

The issue I'm having now is that I can't get the last <% include row.html %> to work in the jQuery. I have debugged this and isolated the issue to this line of code. What can I do to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: It contains a for loop of one of the arrays I'm passing in and rendering the contents with EJS. I'll edit the original post to showcase it.

Comment: Nothing renders onto the page. But I just noticed in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: If I remove the jQuery line the console error message disappears.

Comment: When I view the page source it looks like the HTML markup is rendered from the EJS inside the jquery append function, it's just not getting appended.

Comment: There's a lot of rendered HTML so I don't know how practical it would be to post it all. But probably something in there is preventing the jquery from executing because the scroll stops working when the code is there and works again when I remove it. I'll pour through the source to see what the issue might be. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to escape your HTML, meaning if it contains a single quote, it won't work.

```
$('tbody').append('<p>Johny's HTML AIN'T werkin'!</p>');
```

should be

```
$('tbody').append('<p>Johny\'s HTML IS werkin\'!</p>');
```

Comment: Yeah this was the problem. I ended up working around this by rendering the partial in Express and passing it in as a callback. Then I could call it as HTML in my ajax call. 
Express
`res.render('stories/table-row', {
                ...
              }, function(err, html){
                res.send(html);
              });`
jquery
`$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: nextUrl,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
          $('tbody').append(data);
        }
      });`
This was the problem, so marking this as the answer.

Comment: yah that's one way to do it. I've done that as well. You can also grab any file and put its contents to string server-side, then escape it. Node is the shiznicks, ain't it?

Comment: hmm, down voted for what exactly? I was answering his direct code example. Of course doing it through templates is preferred but please actually read and comprehend the question before down voting my response.

Comment: @JasonSebring, same here, it looks like whoever it was down voted the question and both answers without reasoning.

Answer (score 8):

From my understanding of express/ejs, if you're wanting to add additional EJS templates after the page has loaded (on the client), you'll need to include the [EJS client script](https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/downloads/list) on your page, render the new HTML, and append it with jQuery.

Example:

```
// Get your data
var additionalUsers = { users: [ { name: 'Bob' } ] };

// Moved and renamed the row.html to: /public/templates/row.ejs
var html = new EJS({ url: '/templates/row'}).render(additionalUsers);

// Append the rendered HTML
$('tbody').append(html);
```

Comment: does not work for rendering inside ejs